# Flutter - iOS Simulator "not supported devices connected"

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter, ios-simulator

For some reason, iOS Simulator stopped working. I can open iOS Simulator, but Android Studio not recognizes it. I've already tried to run via terminal, but it says `not supported devices connected`.

When I run `flutter doctor` it returns:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G2136, locale pt-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 9.2)
    ✗ Flutter requires a minimum Xcode version of 11.0.0.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Since I'm on a Macbook 2011, I won't be able to upgrade Xcode. Is it possible to downgrade Flutter and Xcode to an older stable version? Would this solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Check the OS of the connected device and the minimum OS of the application.it might be possible that your device has a lower version of OS then the project.

Comment: Where that file is located?

Comment: open project in Xcode you can find it there.

Comment: On runner file the version is like this `$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)` should I change this?

Comment: That's Bundle name of the app it has no link with it

Comment: couldn`t find application.it in any folder

Comment: open ios folder and then open Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode and check OS.

Comment: My project in iOS have a Runner folder and another Runner folder inside it. But none application.it file. If I select the root folder "Runner" it opens a lot of options in the right screen. Is this place that you're talking?

Answer (score 10):

If Android Studio does not recognize ios simulator even though you can separately open simulator on your Mac, you have to add command line tool on Xcode.

open Xcode then go to Xcode > preferences > select Locations tab. Then select Xcode version from the drop-down menu.

[image]

Open ios simulator again. Then Android Studio will recognize your device.

Comment: Closing and re-opening the iOS simulator fixed it for me. Thanks!